# Suitescript 2.0 Client Script Hanging

Tags: javascript, netsuite, suitescript2.0

I am failing to develop a client script that will check the value of the unitcost line field on inventory adjustments. We have issues internally with inventory adjustments being done with no value.

Below is my code, when deployed it causes the inventory adjustment transaction record to hang.

define(['N/record','N/search','N/ui/dialog', 'N/log'],
/**
*@NApiVersion 2.0
*@NScriptType ClientScript
*/
function saveRecord(currentRecord) {

```
  var lines = currentRecord.getLineCount({sublistId:'inventory'})
  for (var i = 0; i <= lines; i++){
    if (currentRecord.getSublistValue({sublistId: "inventory",fieldId:"unitcost",line:i} == 0.00)) {
        dialog.alert({
            title: 'estimated unit cost error',
            message: 'Enter Estimated Unit Cost!! This should not be $0.00'
        });
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
  }

return {
    
    saveRecord: saveRecord
}
```

});

I have tried the referenced code above expecting to get a dialog box and the record submit to be cancalled, instead the record form hangs while trying to load the inventory sublist (transaction lines).

Comment: in a loop you return true/false on the first iteration, i.e. when `i === 0`. Your loop won't ever move further 0. This is definitely not your intention, so better start from fixing this. Once it's fixed, see if there are any errors in the browser's console, since it's a client script.

Comment: Thank you for the fast response. I'm not sure what you mean there though, I'm declaring and initializing I to zero then saying if I is less than or equal to the number of lines then iterate. Do I have the syntax wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this would cause the script to hang, but you appear to be passing the `context` for the `saveRecord` function incorrectly.  You declare `function saveRecord(currentRecord)` and then use `currentRecord` as if it is an instance of a NetSuite `record.Record` object.

However, the object passed into the `saveRecord` entry point is actually a `context` record.  It *contains* the current record object as a nested object, but is not itself the current record.

```
...
function saveRecord(context) {
    var lines = context.currentRecord.getLineCount({sublistId:'inventory'});
...
```

Also open your browser console to check for any error messages there when you run this script (IE: when you save the record it's deployed on).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you may have mixed SS1 and SS2 samples. The line:
`for (var i = 0; i <= lines; i++){`
should be:
`for (var i = 0; i < lines; i++){`

because SS2 uses 0 based indexing. so for 3 lines your indexes are `0, 1, 2`